# helm installation process on kubernetes

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install helm on a kubernetes cluster

I've downloaded •Linux amd64 Helm 2.12.3.

extracted the tar

`tar -zxvf helm-v2.12.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz`

moved the file

```
mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm

cd /usr/local/bin/helm
```

running ls produces

helm in green

```
helm help
```

produces helm: command not found

```
./helm
```

produces

The Kubernetes package manager to begin working with HELM run the 'helm init' command and displays all of the flags and available commands

```
helm init
```

produces helm: command not found

Comment: What does `./helm` produce?

Comment: I edited the post to include the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep adding `./` in front of the command, or add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH variable.

Comment: when I pwd im in /usr/local/bin/helm and it doesn't work but I have to add ./ and it works

Comment: why do I need to keep adding ./ infront of the command, is there way to add it to the environment so that it always works without the ./

Comment: This will add it to your PATH for the current terminal session: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/loca/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Copy helm binary file to /usr/local/bin directory, or you can add the current directory that holds helm to `$PATH`.

Answer (score -1):

include `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH variable inside `/etc/environment file`.